# Drawing relationship lines in D3 without coordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I am trying to figure out how to draw connection lines between source and target nodes in D3js. I am relatively new to program and have been researching this problem for a few days now. The issue is that I am using randomised positions based on conditions of where the node will be placed on the screen. However since I have no x and y values I cannot connect lines using source and target relationships

I have provided my code below

```
 var testdata =
        [
            {
                "name": "A",
                "type": 1,
                "colour": "red",
                "source": "A",
                "target": "B",
                "x": 50,
                "y" : 500

            },
            {
                "name": "B",
                "type": 2,
                "colour": "blue",
                "source": "B",
                "target": "A",
                "x": 150,
                "y": 350
            },
            {
                "name": "C",
                "type": 3,
                "colour": "yellow",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "D",
                "type": 1,
                "colour": "red",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 3
            },
            {
                "name": "E",
                "type": 2,
                "colour": "blue",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "F",
                "type": 3,
                "colour": "yellow",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "G",
                "type": 1,
                "colour": "red",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "H",
                "type": 2,
                "colour": "blue",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "I",
                "type": 3,
                "colour": "yellow",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "J",
                "type": 1,
                "colour": "red",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "K",
                "type": 2,
                "colour": "blue",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "L",
                "type": 3,
                "colour": "yellow",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "M",
                "type": 1,
                "colour": "red",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "N",
                "type": 2,
                "colour": "blue",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "O",
                "type": 3,
                "colour": "yellow",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "P",
                "type": 1,
                "colour": "red",
                "source": 0,
                "target": 0
            }
        ];



//Set SVG (container) height and width
var  w = 1800,
     h = 1000;

var yposition = 1000;

//Build the SVG container
var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
var i = 0;


var nodes = svg.selectAll("nodes")
        .data(testdata)
        .enter()
        .append("circle");

var nodeattributes = nodes
        .style("fill", function (d) { return d.colour; })
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return (i * 100) + 50})
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("cy", function(d) {if
        (d.type == 1) {return ((1000 * 500/1000))} else if
        (d.type == 2) {return ((1000 * 350/1000))} else if
        (d.type == 3) {return ((1000 *  450/1000))}});

var text = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(testdata)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 100) + 50})
        .attr("y", function(d) {if
        (d.type == 1) {return ((1000 * 500/1000))} else if
        (d.type == 2) {return ((1000 * 350/1000))} else if
        (d.type == 3) {return ((1000 *  450/1000))}})
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

This is my current output,

[image]

Comment: use force layout d3. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout .... https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 .... just dont call the tick function

Comment: `"name": "A",` has `"source": "A", "target": "B",` while `"name": "C",` has `"source": 0, "target": 2` why is this so??